# webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction for opening a link in a default browser

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

Having trouble with a GUI wrapper around a web based chat client I am writing. Basically when someone post a link in the chat room I want to open in the default browser when clicked on. I am using the webkit decidePolicyForNavigationAction.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation
    request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener 
{
NSString *host = [[request URL] host];

    if (![host hasSuffix:@"chatsimply.com"])
    {
        [listener ignore];
        NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
        [ws openURL:request.URL];
    }

        [listener use];
}
```

This does not appear to be seeing the links in the chat room and I am not sure why. I have been searching through some of the forums and Apple documentation without much luck so any help/documentation on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant opening the links in Safari, then this should do it.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
```

If the links aren't highlighted (or what are you trying to do), then I suggest NSLogging the host string to find if it has the suffix you want.

Comment: I can open the links fine just, the main problem is that when I click on a link that has been posted in the chat room (say apple.com) it is not signaling to that delegate that the link has been selected. If I change my default URL I load up from chatsimply to google it opens in my default browser. But when I am in the chatsimply chat room and select a link I do not even see that link show up when I am logging the host URLs.

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Sorry, I don't have an answer for that. Good luck though. :)

Comment: @ACMacalister  Did you ever solve this for links that are dynamically added?  I am still running into the same issue with the delegate not firing for dynamic links that were added after the initial page load.

Comment: @Luke no I did not, I ended up using the macgap project, which should work correctly and you could probably use for reference. https://github.com/maccman/macgap